# Задача «Подстрока»

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, словари, подстрока

Всем здравствуйте! Никак не могу решить следующую задачу.

## «Подстрока»

**Условие:**

В этой задаче Вам требуется найти максимальную по длине подстроку данной строки такую, что каждый символ встречается в ней не более  раз.

**Входные данные:**

В первой строке даны два целых числа  и  (1 ≤  ≤ 100000, 1 ≤  ≤ ), где  — количество символов в строке. Во второй строке  символов — данная строка, состоящая только из строчных латинских букв.

**Выходные данные:**

В выходной файл выведите два числа — длину искомой подстроки и номер её первого символа. Если решений несколько, то выберите самую левую подходящую подстроку.

**Примеры:**

*Ввод 1:*
`3 1`
`abb`

*Вывод 1:*
`2 1`

*Ввод 2:*
`5 2`
`ababa`

*Вывод 2:*
`4 1`

### Мой код:

```
n, k = map(int, input().split())
s = input()
d = dict().fromkeys(s, 0)
l = 0

for i in range(n):
  sym = s[i]
  if d[sym] <= k:
    d[sym] += 1
  else:
    break

print(i - l, l + 1)
```

Тестирующая система выдаёт ошибку «Программа выдаёт неверный ответ». Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём я совершил ошибку?

Comment: Искомая строка не обязана быть префиксом.

Comment: @Qwertiy, здравствуйте! Не совсем понятно, что Вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: @Daniil Savinov Вы решаете только для подстрок, которые начинаются с начала исходной строки (являются её префиксами)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делаем два индекса - левый и правый.

Двигаем правый, подсчитывая количество каждого символа на текущий момент в словарь со счётчиком.

Когда один из счётчиков становится больше k - останавливаемся, фиксируем длину как разницу правого и левого.

Двигаем левый индекс, уменьшая счётчики для каждого символа. Когда счётчик с превышением уменьшается - останавливаемся, и начинаем снова двигать правый индекс. И т.д.

```
from collections import Counter
s = 'abcaabaacacababca'
k = 2
left = 0
right = -1
n = len(s)
cntr = Counter()
maxlen = 0
maxleft = -1
while right < n:
    while right < n:
        right += 1
        if right == n:
            if right - left > maxlen:
                maxlen = right - left
                maxleft = left
            break
        ch = s[right]
        cntr[ch] += 1
        if cntr[ch]> k:
            if right - left > maxlen:
                maxlen = right - left
                maxleft = left
            break
    while left < right:
        ch = s[left]
        left += 1
        cntr[ch] -= 1
        if cntr[ch] == k:
            break

print(maxlen, maxleft)
```

Comment: А чем ответ отличается от моего?

Comment: @Aziz Umarov Тем, что он линейный, а не квадратичный. Он не проверяет все подстроки

Comment: Добавлю что не стоит бегать в сторону увеличения подстроки если k уже превысил ожидаемый. и что если вы тоже сделаете все проверки что и я. Тогда у вас квадратичный или у меня линейный?

Comment: Как раз здесь алгоритм не бегает - `становится больше k - останавливаемся`

Comment: Проверка всех подстрок подразумевает все возможные начала и концы - это квадратичный алгоритм. После выделения строки нужно ещё проверить её свойства - это уже может дать кубический алгоритм. В данном же оба индекса проходят в одну лишь сторону, делая не более n шагов каждый.

Comment: Я лишь указал что нужно считать и для ясности бегать по разным концам. У вас тоже отдельный цикл на каждый конец так что говорить о линейности не стоит

Comment: Никакой из индексов у меня назад не возвращается, так что линейный.

Comment: А где я написал что у меня возвращается? И с чего вы взяли что я буду реализовывать именно так. Поймите это описание алгоритма. а не реализация. У вас также описание. Вот только я не вижу принципиальной разницы. И еще вы как будите подсчитывать К, увеличение строки это не проблема вот как с уменьшением.

Comment: `Пробежаться по всем возможным подстрокам` - это квадрат.

Comment: Это опять описание. Здесь не говорится об оптимизации и прочих. Идея только нужно проверить все подстроки и найти самую большую. Понятно что имея самый большой шаблон не стоит смотреть в сторону уменьшения и вовсе. Но это лишь реализация. Человек реализовал и у него не работает. Другой пишет "Искомая строка не обязана быть префиксом." вы ребята о чем?

Comment: Добавил улучшения к вашим догадкам

Comment: @Aziz Umarov Вероятно, Ваше описание оказалось недостаточно ясным для меня.

Comment: Да все возможно. Извините если что не так.

Comment: Добавил несколько формул для подсчета К для строки которая увеличивается и уменьшается

Comment: Конечно извиняюсь но я Pyton не знаюю так что реализовать на нем не смогу тем более с применением библиотек

Comment: @MBo, большое Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Задача не сложная нужно

Вход `K N Str`

1. Функция которая считает `k` для заданной строки. `CountK(anystr)`
2. Пробежаться по всем возможным подстрокам искомой строки и вычислять k для нее. Если `CountK(substr) <= K && len(substr) > lenKmax` тогда обновляем переменные `kMax, srtartIndex, LenKmax`.

И к стати все подстроки получаются циклом для конца подстроки и циклом для начала подстроки.

Добавлю что не стоит бегать в сторону увеличения подстроки если `k` уже превысил ожидаемый. И понятно что не стоит искать подстроку в сторону уменьшения и вовсе имея уже на руках большую. Т.е двигаться по подстрокам уже имея при себе `lenMax`

Извиняюсь пишу с телефона. Завтра попробую написать код.

**UPD**

**Подсчет countK**
`a = a[26]` - массив счетчиков на каждый символ в строке

Понятно что `CountK` - это `max(a)` (максимальный из массива `a`); нахождение постоянно max(a) для каждой строки не много накладно, но можно это сделать по другому.

Ясно что при добавление одного символа в строку `CountK` будет равен `CountK(string + char) = max(a[indexOf(char)]++, CountK(string))`

и уменьшение строки на один символ
`CountK(-char + string)` = if (a[indexOf(char)] < CountK(string)) тогда это CountK(string) иначе уменьшаем a[indexOf(char)]-- и ищем `max(a)`

Comment: Не получится - во время не уложится.

Comment: Конечно извиняюсь но я Pyton не знаю так что реализовать на нем не смогу тем более с применением библиотек.