# Не проходит 3 тест, не могу подобрать тест, где будет выявлена ошибка. В конце наставил костыли, другого варианта не нашел

Tags: python

В этой задаче Вам требуется найти максимальную по длине подстроку данной строки, такую что каждый символ встречается в ней не более k раз.

Формат ввода
В первой строке даны два целых числа n и k (1 ≤ n ≤ 100000, 1 ≤ k ≤ n ) , где n – количество символов в строке. Во второй строке n символов – данная строка, состоящая только из строчных латинских букв.

Формат вывода
В выходной файл выведите два числа – длину искомой подстроки и номер её первого символа. Если решений несколько, выведите любое.

```
s=str(input()).split()
n=int(s[0])
k=int(s[1])
s=str(input())
lmax=0
l=0
r=0
a=set(s)
a=list(a)
slovar={}
for i in range(len(a)):
    slovar[a[i]]=0
slovar[s[0]]=1
for l in range(n):
    while r<len(s)-1 and slovar[s[r]]<=k:
        r=r+1
        slovar[s[r]]+=1
        
    if r-l>=lmax:
        lmax=r-l
        left=l
        right=r
    slovar[s[l]]-=1
left=left+1
if left>1:
    lmax+=1
print(lmax,left)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Задача «Подстрока»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1165725/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: @n1tr0xs, вопрос не как решить задачу, а как подобрать тест. Поэтому вопрос не является дубликатом. Другое дело, что ТС интересует решение задачи, а не какой тест провалится. Поэтому вопрос - дубликат.

Comment: А с самой короткой строкой вы уже разобрались?

Comment: @MBo спасибо, добавил условие if lmax==0: lmax=1, но третий тест все так же не проходит

Answer (score 0):

Тест. Ожидаемый ответ - вся строка или два символа. На практике ответ - один символ. Это ошибка:

> ```
> $ python substring.py
> 2 1
> ab
> 1 1
> ```

**P.S.** Какие тесты вы делали?

Comment: добрый вечер, подставил ваше условие в код, работает верно, выводит 2 1, где 2- длина строки, 1 - начальный символ

Comment: благодаря комментарию выше, учел момент с длиной строки  в один символ, но 3-ий тест все так же не проходит

Comment: Я ещё раз перепроверил ваш код и мой тест. Возвращается неправильный ответ `1 1`.

Comment: извиняюсь, случайно поставил пробел между ab, сейчас попробую разобраться

Comment: добавил строчку if lmax<=1: lmax=lmax+1, данный вариант исключил, но третий тест все равно ни в какую. Слишком много костылей получается в этой задаче, а понять из-за чего эти костыли понадобились как-то не выходит.

Comment: тест на 3 1 abc  тоже не проходит, постараюсь разобраться почему не захватывает всю строку, спасибо!

Comment: В коде видны две ошибки: правый край захватывает символы у которых вхождений больше `k`, левый край умеет двигаться только одну позицию.

Comment: Я бы не пытался стегать мёртвую лошадь. Надо переписать алгоритм с обоснованием. Сейчас вы пытаетесь чинить отдельные тесты, так далеко не уйти.

Comment: вы правы, постараюсь разобраться завтра на свежую голову с новым кодом, спасибо за помощь!