# Решение задачи со строками на C#

Tags: c#

Я пытаюсь решить задачу

> Требуется найти максимальную по длине подстроку данной строки, такую что каждый символ встречается в ней не более k раз.

Входные данные

> В первой строке даны два целых числа n и k (1 ≤ n ≤ 100000, 1 ≤ k ≤ n ) , где n – количество символов в строке. Во второй строке n символов – данная строка, состоящая только из строчных латинских букв.

Выходные данные

> В выходной файл выведите два числа – длину искомой подстроки и номер её первого символа. Если решений несколько, выведите любое.

Примеры

входные данные

```
3 1

abb
```

выходные данные

```
2 1
```

входные данные

```
5 2

ababa
```

выходные данные

```
4 1
```

Вот мой код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       
        string[] str = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        long n = long.Parse(str[0]);
        long k = long.Parse(str[1]);
        string mass = Console.ReadLine();
        Dictionary<char, long> dic = new Dictionary<char, long>();
        long max_len = 0;
        long start_simv = 1;
        int l = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < n; r++)
        {
            if (dic.ContainsKey(mass[r]) != true)
                dic.Add(mass[r], 0);
            dic[mass[r]]++;
            while (dic[mass[r]] > k)
            {
                if (dic[mass[l]] > 0)
                    dic[mass[l]]--;
                l++;
            }
            if (max_len < r - l + 1)
            {
                max_len = r - l + 1;
                start_simv = l + 1;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(max_len + " " + start_simv);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Выдает неправильный ответ. Задача тут: https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?chapterid=112554#1

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Известно, на каких данных программа даёт неправильный ответ?

Comment: нет, не известно

Comment: [Console.ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-8.0): "Возвращаемая строка не содержит завершающие символы. По умолчанию метод считывает входные данные из 256-символьного буфера. Так как сюда входят Environment.NewLine символы, метод может считывать строки, содержащие до 254 символов. Чтобы прочитать более длинные строки, вызовите OpenStandardInput(Int32) метод ."

Comment: не совсем понял, что вы имели ввиду. Возможно объяснение подробнее

Comment: Я прочитал в документации что `Console.Readline` не всегда считывает строку целиком. Если строка длинная может быть прочитано только её начало. Проверить на Windows я не могу.  На Linux поведение не воспроизводится, но на Linux другой рантайм (mono). Попробуйте заменить ввод на чтение из стандартного потока. Возможно, это исправит ситуацию.

Comment: попробовал так, не вышло (отправил код ответом на вопрос)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy вообще я удивлён. Ведь те, кто пилил задачу и тесты, должны были позаботиться об этом.

Comment: @aepot, ваш код проходит проверяющую систему?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я не могу проверить, не у компа. С телефона очень сложно генерить файл для заливки. Там нет текстового поля для вставки кода.

Comment: А кто как понимает "такую что каждый символ встречается в ней"? Каждый символ подстроки или каждый символ входной строки?

Comment: В общем, я перепробовал всякое, пробовал лить на сайт разные варианты. Не проходит ни одного теста. Хотя другую задачу мне удалось сдать, то есть формат файла у автора правильный. Возможно сам тест сломан. Ещё он показыват неверный расход памяти (каждый раз максимальный), что тоже наводит на мысль, что тесты сломаны. Пишите авторам тестов.

Comment: aepot нашёл ответ [Задача «Подстрока»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1165776/373567)